# Negation in "John is NOT able to express his needs appropriately NOR to initiate communication", is it right?

Tags: negation, coordination, neither-nor

> John is not able to express his needs appropriately nor to initiate communication.

Is the grammar correct ?

My question is are the negative words used correctly. So is it possible to use two of them in the sentence? Is my use of the two negative words correct here, or does it cause a problem. If there is a problem, what can I do to correct it? Why would this solve the problem?

Comment: Can you edit this question to make it more suitable for this site, i.e, related to English language learning? Add some context perhaps?

Comment: Hi user25559. Welcome to ELL. It's always a good idea to give lost of details in your question. It's important to show why you think there might be a problem with the grammar, for example, because otherwise people don't know what help you need! :-) Very nice question subject though +1

Comment: Would 'neither . . . .nor' be better?

Comment: @Araucaria: You mind putting this on http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2530/10820, given your labor in making the question answerable?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your questions one by one:

> Is it possible to use two negative words in the sentence?

Absolutely. For such a sentence to make sense the negatives are commonly of different types (*I'm not negative, nor am I wrong*), since when they aren't (*I'm not **not** talking to the police officer...*) the general feel is that the speaker is trying to be intentionally misleading (*I didn't do nothing!*) or obtuse (Was it interesting? *Well, it wasn't uninteresting...*).

> Is my use of the two negative words correct here?

It is indeed. The negative conjunction *nor* ties the dependent clause into the rest of the sentence grammatically. I might suggest putting a comma after *appropriately* (commonly referred to as [*the Oxford comma*](http://www.grammarly.com/blog/2015/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/)), but the sentence is still correct without it.